# Apache Commons Compress: ZipArchiveEntry.getUnixMode() always returns 0

Tags: java, apache-commons-compress

When analyzing the resulting file, the value is written correctly so `setUnixMode()` probably works ok, but `getUnixMode()` always returns 0. Does anyone have any experience with this?

```
File file = new File("Test.file");
ZipArchiveOutputStream zipArchiveOutputStream = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));   
ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry = new ZipArchiveEntry("Entry");  
zipArchiveEntry.setUnixMode(0744);
zipArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(zipArchiveEntry);
zipArchiveOutputStream.write("TestBytes".getBytes());
zipArchiveOutputStream.closeArchiveEntry();
zipArchiveOutputStream.close();
                        
ZipArchiveInputStream zipArchiveInputStream = new ZipArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
ZipArchiveEntry entryOut = zipArchiveInputStream.getNextZipEntry();
System.out.println(entryOut.getUnixMode());
```

Answer (score 0):

getUnixMode() returns 0 when platform != PLATFORM_UNIX (see [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-compress/blob/da22ecf0fd91cdd5abd105692ff81ba40a5c27cf/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveEntry.java#L374) for the source code). So you also have to specify the platform: `zipArchiveEntry.setPlatform(ZipArchiveEntry.PLATFORM_UNIX)`

Comment: Still zeros :(.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the design of the ZIP format, it is not possible to read the unix mode when the ZIP is opened as a stream.

> ZipArchiveInputStream is limited and may even return false contents in some cases, use ZipFile whenever possible. See the ZIP documentation page for details. This limitation is a result of streaming data vs using random access and not a limitation of Compress' specific implementation.

[source](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/limitations.html)

The fix is to use ZipFile instead. I have tried this and can confirm that when doing so it works.